# ImageMagick: How to fix delegate failed `'potrace' error

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to convert a PDF to SVG with Image Magick. I run the following command:

```
magick input.pdf output.svg
```

I get the following error:

```
magick: delegate failed `'potrace' --svg --output '%o' '%i'' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1911.

How does one fix this?
```

Answer (score 18):

Install the potrace dependency:

```
brew install potrace
```

Once installed, the original command worked for me.

The error is happening because ImageMagick relies on [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/), which was not installed on my machine.

Comment: bash: brew: command not found

Comment: @belkka - `brew` refers to [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) a commonly used script to install packages on MacOS. Go to [Homebrew’s website](https://brew.sh/) and follow the installation instructions.